# Can't update rows of google spreadsheet API using Android Studio.

Tags: android, api, authentication, spreadsheet, edit

I am writing a code for an app using the android studio and so far I am able to retrieve data from a google spreadsheet. 
I used the following code:

```
package com.example.tolotrasamuel.aluoneapp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetService;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.ListEntry;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.ListFeed;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.WorksheetEntry;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.WorksheetFeed;
import com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException;
import com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException;

public class GetDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Activity, Void, Void> {

   Activity myActivity;
   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground(Activity... arg0) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      myActivity = arg0[0];

      try {
         getData();
      } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (ServiceException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

      try {
         String xmlString = XMLCreator.CreateSpreadSheetToXML();
         FileOperations.StoreData(xmlString);
//       Log.d("hello",xmlString);
      } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (TransformerException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return null;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      Intent i = new Intent(myActivity.getApplicationContext(),TransApp.class);
      i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      myActivity.startActivity(i);
      myActivity.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
      myActivity.finish();
   }

   private void getData() throws AuthenticationException,
         MalformedURLException, IOException, ServiceException,
         URISyntaxException {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService(
            "MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1");
      service.setProtocolVersion(SpreadsheetService.Versions.V3);

      URL SPREADSHEET_URL = new URL(
            "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/1ZNbR2eECA3PX9RSfFw7R0H50JpALJC50CQLSvvS-ySw/public/full");

      WorksheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_URL,
            WorksheetFeed.class);
      List<WorksheetEntry> worksheets = feed.getEntries();
      WorksheetEntry worksheet = worksheets.get(0);
      Log.d("hello", "Worksheet name is "
            + worksheet.getTitle().getPlainText());

      // URL listFeedUrl = worksheet.getListFeedUrl();
      URL listFeedUrl = new URI(worksheet.getListFeedUrl().toString())
            .toURL();

      Log.d("hello", "URL is \n " + listFeedUrl.toString());

      ListFeed listFeed = service.getFeed(listFeedUrl, ListFeed.class);

      ArrayList<String> CategoryArray = new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList<String> ShuttleArray = new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList<String> Email1_Array = new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList<String> Email2_Array = new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList<String> RouteArray = new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList<String> TimeArray = new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList<String> S_No_Array = new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList<String> Off1_Array = new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList<String> Cohort_Array = new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList<String> NumberStud_Array = new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList<String> Res2_Array = new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList<String> Mob1_Array = new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList<String> Mob2_Array = new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList<String> Tag_Array = new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList<String> Day_Array = new ArrayList<String>();

      ListEntry TempList = listFeed.getEntries().get(0);
      for(String tag:TempList.getCustomElements().getTags()){
         Tag_Array.add(tag);
      }

      for (ListEntry row : listFeed.getEntries()) {
         for (String tag : row.getCustomElements().getTags()) {
            if (tag.equals("s.no.")) {
               S_No_Array.add(ProperValue(row.getCustomElements()
                     .getValue(tag)));
            }
            if (tag.equals("route")) {
               RouteArray.add(ProperValue(row.getCustomElements()
                     .getValue(tag)));
            }
            if (tag.equals("time")) {
               TimeArray.add(ProperValue(row.getCustomElements()
                     .getValue(tag)));
            }
            if (tag.equals("category")) {
               CategoryArray.add(ProperValue(row.getCustomElements()
                     .getValue(tag)));
            }
            if (tag.equals("shuttle")) {
               ShuttleArray.add(ProperValue(row.getCustomElements()
                     .getValue(tag)));
            }
            if (tag.equals("o1")) {
               Off1_Array.add(ProperValue(row.getCustomElements()
                     .getValue(tag)));
            }
            if (tag.equals("cohort")) {
               Cohort_Array.add(ProperValue(row.getCustomElements()
                     .getValue(tag)));
            }

            if (tag.equals("numberofstudents")) {
               NumberStud_Array.add(ProperValue(row.getCustomElements()
                     .getValue(tag)));
            }
            if (tag.equals("r2")) {
               Res2_Array.add(ProperValue(row.getCustomElements()
                     .getValue(tag)));
            }
            if (tag.equals("m1")) {
               Mob1_Array.add(ProperValue(row.getCustomElements()
                     .getValue(tag)));
            }
            if (tag.equals("m2")) {
               Mob2_Array.add(ProperValue(row.getCustomElements()
                     .getValue(tag)));
            }
            if (tag.equals("e1")) {
               Email1_Array.add(ProperValue(row.getCustomElements()
                     .getValue(tag)));
            }
            if (tag.equals("e2")) {
               Email2_Array.add(ProperValue(row.getCustomElements()
                     .getValue(tag)));
            }
            if (tag.equals("day")) {
               Day_Array.add(ProperValue(row.getCustomElements()
                     .getValue(tag)));
            }
         }

      }

      XMLParserClass.CategoryArray = CategoryArray;
      XMLParserClass.ShuttleArray = ShuttleArray;
      XMLParserClass.Email1_Array = Email1_Array;
      XMLParserClass.Email2_Array = Email2_Array;
      XMLParserClass.RouteArray = RouteArray;
      XMLParserClass.Off1_Array = Off1_Array;
      XMLParserClass.Cohort_Array = Cohort_Array;
      XMLParserClass.TimeArray = TimeArray;
      XMLParserClass.NumberStud_Array = NumberStud_Array;
      XMLParserClass.Res2_Array = Res2_Array;
      XMLParserClass.Mob1_Array = Mob1_Array;
      XMLParserClass.Mob2_Array = Mob2_Array;
      XMLParserClass.Tag_Array = Tag_Array;
      XMLParserClass.Day_Array = Day_Array;

   }

   public String ProperValue(String input) {
      if (input == null) {
         return new String("");
      } else {
         return input;
      }

   }

}
```

This works perfectly but when I am trying to edit the rows of the spreadsheet, it gives me an error: 
I used the following code:

```
package com.example.tolotrasamuel.newapispreadsheet;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.*;
import com.google.gdata.util.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.*;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;

/**
 * Created by Tolotra Samuel on 23/08/2016.
 */
public class SisUpdateMe extends AsyncTask<Activity, Object, Void> {

    Activity myActivity;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Activity... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        myActivity = arg0[0];

        try {
            updateaction();
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return  null;
    }


    public static void updateaction()
            throws AuthenticationException, MalformedURLException, IOException, ServiceException,URISyntaxException {

        SpreadsheetService service =
                new SpreadsheetService("MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1");

        service.setProtocolVersion(SpreadsheetService.Versions.V3);
        File p12 = new File("./key.p12");

        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
        String[] SCOPESArray = {"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/1En7qJ5aG2U9fEMSoh-wW1FXoqzNWQfMB4v6-vcN5pVg/private/full", "https://docs.google.com/feeds"};
        final List SCOPES = Arrays.asList(SCOPESArray);
        GoogleCredential credential = null;
        try {
            credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                    .setTransport(httpTransport)
                    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                    .setServiceAccountId("732698423440-ucindhfeddmul5f2dmp42kuv18r3mecq.apps.googleusercontent.com")
                    .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
                    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(p12)
                    .build();
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
        // TODO: Authorize the service object for a specific user (see other sections)

        // Define the URL to request.  This should never change.
        URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL(
                "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/1En7qJ5aG2U9fEMSoh-wW1FXoqzNWQfMB4v6-vcN5pVg/private/full");


        WorksheetFeed worksheetFeed = service.getFeed(
                SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL, WorksheetFeed.class);
        List<WorksheetEntry> worksheets = worksheetFeed.getEntries();
        WorksheetEntry worksheet = worksheets.get(0);
        Log.d("hello", "Worksheet name is "
                + worksheet.getTitle().getPlainText());

        // Fetch the list feed of the worksheet.
        URL listFeedUrl = new URI(worksheet.getListFeedUrl().toString())
                .toURL();

        Log.d("hello", "URL is \n " + listFeedUrl.toString());

        ListFeed listFeed = service.getFeed(listFeedUrl, ListFeed.class);

        // TODO: Choose a row more intelligently based on your app's needs.
        ListEntry row = listFeed.getEntries().get(0);

        // Update the row's data.
        row.getCustomElements().setValueLocal("route", "Sarah");
        row.getCustomElements().setValueLocal("day", "Hunt");
        row.getCustomElements().setValueLocal("shuttle", "32");
        row.getCustomElements().setValueLocal("category", "154");

        // Save the row using the API.
        row.update();
    }
    }
```

I don't know where am I doing wrong. I think this is problem of authentification.
I would be glad if you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are using the google spreadsheet API V3. This version is deprecated. Instead, use the new version: V4. Follow this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets) to know how to update rows